# Shell script error: [: 0: unary operator expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Using this if statment in `bash`:

```
if [ "$TOTAL_LOAD" >= "2" ];then

RESULT=$STATE_WARNING

msg_text="The system load on $HOST is greater than 200% please investigate {$TOTAL_LOAD}"

fi
```

Getting the error:

```
 line 28: [: 0: unary operator expected
```

Not seeing the error in my ways.  Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash uses different operators for string vs arithmetic comparison. You want `-ge` instead of `>=`:

```
if [ "$TOTAL_LOAD" -ge "2" ];then
```

Answer (score 1):

If I run this by hand I see the error:

```
pokyo. if [ "0" >= "2" ]; then echo hi; fi
bash: [: 0: unary operator expected
```

The problem is that ">=" is not a valid operator for `test`.  Instead you must write `-ge`:

```
pokyo. if [ "0" -ge "2" ]; then echo hi; fi
```